# Consumir DLL C no VB6 ou C#

Tags: c#, c, c++, visual-basic-6

Tenho uma DLL (gbasmsb_library.dll) disponibilizado pela [Farmácia Popular](https://aplicacao.saude.gov.br/portalfarmacia/gbas/GBASMSB_1.0.1.5-Client.zip) responsável por retornar algumas funções para interação com este ambiente. 

Penso que seja uma DLL escrita em C, preciso consumir esta DLL em **VB6 OU C#**.

No [Guia do programador](http://aplicacao.saude.gov.br/portalfarmacia/gbas/GAS_GBAS_MS_Guia_Programador_Web_v2.1_20110118.pdf) do programador tenho as seguintes informações para o uso da DLL:

**1:**

> Sintaxe:

```
const char* IdentificaEstacao();
```

> Valor de retorno: Uma string contendo o DNA da máquina.

**2:**

> Sintaxe:

```
const char* PegaSolicitacao( 
const char* CNPJ, 
const char* CPF, 
const char* CRM, 
const char* UF_CRM, 
const char* DT_EMISSAO );
```

> Uma string que será utilizada para validação da solicitação através da geração da assinatura da 
>   máquina.

Em **VB6** consegui consumir a primeira função (1), já a segunda retorna erro:

> 49 Bad DLL calling convention

**Código VB6:**

```
Private Declare Function PegaSolicitacao Lib "c:\temp\gbasmsb_library.dll" (ByRef CNPJ As String, ByRef CPF As String, ByRef CRM As String, ByRef UF_CRM As String, ByRef DT_EMISSAO As String) As String
Private Declare Function IdentificaEstacao Lib "c:\temp\gbasmsb_library.dll" () As String
    Private Sub Form_Load()
      MsgBox (IdentificaEstacao) //1 - retorno OK    

      Dim CNPJ As String, CPF As String, CRM As String, UF_CRM As String, DT_EMISSAO As String

      Dim resp As String
      CNPJ = "98352942000133"
      CPF = "72794534491"
      CRM = "7347"
      UF_CRM = "AM"
      DT_EMISSAO = "01/01/1991"
      resp = PegaSolicitacao(CNPJ, CPF, CRM, UF_CRM, DT_EMISSAO) //2 - ERRO
    end sub
```

Já alterei a assinatura da função para byVal, mudei os parâmetro para array também sem sucesso.

**Código C#** Sem sucesso na chamada de nenhuma FUNÇÃO.

```
[DllImport(@"c:\temp\gbasmsb_library.dll")]
private static extern string PegaSolicitacao(string cnpj, string cpf, string crm, string ufCrm, string dtEmissao);

[DllImport(@"c:\temp\gbasmsb_library.dll")]
private static extern string IdentificaEstacao();

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var cnpj = "98352942000133";
    var cpf = "72794534491";
    var crm = "7347";
    var ufCrm = "PI";
    var dtEmissao = "01/01/1991";
    //MessageBox.Show(PegaSolicitacao(ref cnpj, ref cnpj, ref cnpj, ref cnpj, ref cnpj));
    //ERRO
    MessageBox.Show(PegaSolicitacao(cnpj, cpf, crm, ufCrm, dtEmissao));
    //ERRO
    IdentificaEstacao();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bibliotecas em C/C++ possuem convenção de chamadas (a maneira pela qual o método é manipulado pela CPU, sua pilha, etc), isto implica em otmização.

> https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k2b2ssfy.aspx

Enfim, sua solução está aqui:

> https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa232602%28v=vs.60%29.aspx

Tenha certeza de que os argumentos estão corretos e na mesma ordem, bem como o nome da função, também especifique a convenção de chamada diretamente no atributo:

```
    // analise sua DLL, talvez não seja StdCall, pode ser Cdecl ou outras convenções
    [DllImport("Foo.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern void FooMethod();
```

Talvez alguns pontos a mais sejam necessários como `CharSet` (Unicode ou Ansi) e `ExactSpelling=true`

**Outro ponto importante:**

> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/370079/pinvoke-for-c-function-that-returns-char

Strings (char* para string) -> Use System.IntPtr já que char* é um ponteiro, você precisará criar a string depois de chamar o método copiando por `Marshal`.

**Assinatura das Funções**

```
public class Gba
{

    //const char* IdentificaEstacao();
    [return: MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.AnsiBStr)]
    [DllImport("gba.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall, ExactSpelling = true)]
    public static extern string IdentificaEstacao();

    //const char* PegaSolicitacao( const char* CNPJ, const char* CPF, const char* CRM, const char* UF_CRM, const char* DT_EMISSAO );
    [return: MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.AnsiBStr)]
    [DllImport("gba.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall, ExactSpelling = true)]
    public static extern string PegaSolicitacao(string CNPJ, string CPF, string CRM, string UF_CRM, string DT_EMISSAO );

    //const char* PegaConfirmacao( const char* CNPJ, const char* NU_AUTORIZACAO, const char* NU_CUPOM_FISCAL );
    [return: MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.AnsiBStr)]
    [DllImport("gba.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall, ExactSpelling = true)]
    public static extern string PegaConfirmacao(string CNPJ, string NU_AUTORIZACAO, IntPtr NU_CUPOM_FISCAL );
}
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta @leonardo-bosquett tentei várias configurações mas sem sucesso. `Foi feita uma tentativa de se carregar um programa com um formato incorreto. (Exceção de HRESULT: 0x8007000B)`

Comment: Modifiquei a resposta, sua exceção é causada, provavelmente, porque você está criando um executável 64 bits (a DLL do portal da saúde está em 32 bits). Veja isto nas propriedades do projeto

Comment: Realmente matou a charada tava ANYCPU mudei para x86 e funcionou! Fiz também algumas mudanças para retornar o valor em string, segue o código para atualizar sua resposta: 

`[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.AnsiBStr)]
public static extern string IdentificaEstacao();` Obrigado @leonardo-bosquett.

Comment: A assinatura das outras funções recebem `string` ao invés de `IntPtr` @leonardo-bosquett

Answer (score 0):

As DLL's em c não trabalham muito bem com string.
A classe string do c/c++ é completamente diferente das do visual basic 6.
Como está dando um erro de bad calling, que é um erro de checagem de assinatura, você pode tentar tirar o "string" do vb6:
Como você colocou as declaração em c fica mais fácil:

```
Private Declare Function PegaSolicitacao Lib "c:\temp\gbasmsb_library.dll" (ByRef CNPJ As any, ByRef CPF As Any, ByRef CRM As Any, ByRef UF_CRM As Any, ByRef DT_EMISSAO As Any) As Any

Private Sub Form_Load()
dim Cnpj () as byte

dim CPF () as byte

dim UF_CRM() as byte

dim DT_EMISSAO() as byte


dim CRM () as byte
Cnpj = strconv("777383" & chr(0),vbFromUnicode)

CPF = strconv("777383" & chr(0),vbFromUnicode)

CRM = strconv("777383" & chr(0),vbFromUnicode)

UF_CRM = strconv("DF" & chr(0), vbFromUnicode)

DT_EMISSAO  = strconv("838832" & chr(0), vbFromUnicode)

dim resp() as byte
'preencher a variavel antes de pegar o retorno , ou vb6 ira travar sem explicação

resp = space$(1000)

resp = PegaSolicitacao (Cnpj ,CPF ,CRM,UF_CRM,DT_EMISSAO  )

dim resposta as string 

resposta = strconv(resp , vbunicode)

'retira o 0 no fim que veio na resposta
resposta = replace( resposta , chr(0),"")

msgbox resposta

End Sub
```

Espero ter ajudado