# Consumir DLL feita em Delphi 7 no C#

Tags: c#, delphi-7

Estou com a necessidade de criar uma `DLL` em Delphi 7 e consumi-la no C#, quando os parâmetros e retorno são int não há problemas, o problema ocorre quando tento utilizar string no retorno, coloquei no Delphi um MessageDlg e vi que o parâmetro de entrada está indo corretamente, no *BreakPoint* não gera exceção, simplesmente a aplicação console de teste morre quando efetuo a chamada.

Delphi:

```
function Mensagem(texto: string): PAnsiChar; stdcall;
var
  msg: str
begin
  msg := texto;
  Result := PAnsiChar(msg);
end;

exports
  Mensagem;
```

C#:

```
[DllImport(@"teste.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
 static extern string Mensagem([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.AnsiBStr)]string msg);
```

Comment: O painel de _output_ deveria dar um direcionamento. Já checou o que tem lá logo após a aplicação morrer ou aumentar o nível de detalhamento para _diagnostic_

Comment: Dependendo dos parâmetros que coloco, ele pode gerar exceção, mudei para ShortString e me retornou Managed Debugging Assistant 'PInvokeStackImbalance' : 'Uma chamada para a função PInvoke 'ConsoleApp1!ConsoleApp1.Program::Mensagem' desbalanceou a pilha. Isso ocorreu provavelmente porque a assinatura gerenciada de PInvoke não corresponde à assinatura de destino não gerenciada. Verifique se a convenção e o parâmetro de chamada da assinatura de PInvoke são iguais aos da assinatura não gerenciada de destino.

Answer (score 4):

Achei a solução nesse post [Aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/50507/21165)

Só precisei adicionar o tipo de Retorno e o método que importo da DLL ficou assim.

```
    [return: MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.AnsiBStr)]
    [DllImport(@"teste.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    static extern string Mensagem([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.AnsiBStr)]string msg);
```